# How to set a time value for a WKInterfaceTimer using a Slider

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am creating a test app to get used to WatchKit, and was wondering if it possible to use a slider to set a countdown time. I have this so far:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet weak var footText: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerOutput: WKInterfaceTimer!

@IBAction func button() {
}
@IBAction func timeSlider(value: Float) {
var myValue = String(format: "Value is %f", value)
    func setAttributedText(attributedText: NSAttributedString?) {}

}
var testtest = "This is a test"

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

}
```

Is it possible to change the value of the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of your timer, you can set it like this :

- First of all, you use your slider to change the value of the countTime
- After that you can set the timer, depending on your countTime:

  timer.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: countTime))
          timer.start()

Hope this helps!